# Suppressing PDF Conversion Error Messages in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to open up PDF documents for manipulation in VBA. For the most part, the PDFs open in Word without a problem. However, I believe there are some PDFs with user added "comments" in them (the kind that you hover over and the PDF shows what comment the user added) that are generating the error code. I use this to open:

```
Dim pdfDoc As Word.Document
Set pdfDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=FSOFile.path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto)
```

And the error generated is this:

> "This PDF contains interactive features that are not supported by PDF Reflow. Word will not display this content."

Is there a way to suppress/avoid this message? If I step through this and continue execution, the PDF does open and the rest of my code works.

Comment: That isn't an error message, it's a notification that you get when opening a file. You could try setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` but it may not have any effect.

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized that!